# Issues sending data from arduino to php file in google cloud

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, arduino

If I send data from arduino to a php file in localhost to send data to firebase it works, but I can not send to a php file in google cloud. Arduino returns that connects to it but not insert data in php file to send to firebase.
I have firewall able for http.

This is the at command to send.

```
String cmdString = "AT+HTTPGET=\"http://35.187.182.xxx/submit_data01.php?data1=" + lat +"&data2=" + lng + "&data3=" + mac + "&data4=" + String(flag) + "\"";
```

If anybody knows how to solve.

I'm not sure If I need to set some extra api.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt install -y php libapache2-mod-php

systemctl restart apache2
```

These commands install PHP and the Apache module libapache2-mod-php, then restart the Apache service to apply the changes.